# Why does Fourier Series have $\sin$ and $\cos$ Components

Tags: fourier-series

While we look at Fourier Series there are both $\sin$ and $\cos$ components.But I think $\sin$ component is ony needed to describe wave.why there is also an $\cos$ component in Fourier Series?

$S_n(x)$=$A_0 + \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} (A_n\cos(nx) + B_n\sin(nx))$

Comment: Hai Justin I'm Kevin I have joined stackexchange. I hope it has something to do with phase difference but keep on looking for other comments

Answer (score 5):

Note that the value of the series

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}B_n\sin(nx)\tag{1}$$

for $x=0$ is always zero, regardless of the coefficients $B_n$ (assuming convergence). Furthermore, since the functions $\sin(nx)$ are odd, (1) can only represent odd functions. So you cannot represent general functions with the series (1). This is why you also need the cosine terms. As an alternative, you could as well use a representation with phases in the argument of the sine:

$$f(x)=A_0+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}C_n\sin(nx+\phi_n)\tag{2}$$

In this case you don't need any cosine terms because of the phases $\phi_n$. The representation in (2) is equivalent to the series in your question using sine and cosine terms. You can see this by using the identity $\sin(\alpha+\beta)=\cos\alpha\sin\beta+\sin\alpha\cos\beta$:

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}C_n\sin(nx+\phi_n)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left[C_n\sin\phi_n\cos(nx)+C_n\cos\phi_n\sin(nx)\right]$$

So the coefficients $A_n$ and $B_n$ in your question are

$$A_n=C_n\sin\phi_n\\
B_n=C_n\cos\phi_n$$

And the other way around you have

$$C_n=\sqrt{A_n^2+B_n^2}\\
\phi_n=\arctan\left(\frac{A_n}{B_n}\right)\quad(\pm\pi)$$

Comment: whether there would be a case in which we have to use both the $\cos$ and $\sin$ components in fourier series?

Comment: @justin: As I said in my answer, if you have a function that is not odd (and also not even), then you need both terms, or only one term *with* phases, as in Eq. (2) of my answer.

Comment: could you cite a function that wouldn't neither be odd nor even.

Comment: @justin: $f(x)=\sin(x+\pi/4)$

Comment: :could you say why it is neither even nor odd.

Comment: @justin: In principle you should look up the basics yourself, this is really straightforward: odd function: $f(x)=-f(-x)$. Even function: $f(x)=f(-x)$. Now check for yourself if the function I gave you satisfies either of the two properties. Or simply plot it and have a look.

Comment: :I have plotted the graph:http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sin%28x%2Bpi%2F4%29&lk=4.But how to observe it.I know that for an even function it would be symmetric of y.But what can I do to check whether it is odd or not?

Comment: @justin: It should be *asymmetrical*, like $\sin(x)$. The function you plotted is neither of the two, so it's neither even nor odd.

Comment: :But if we use 'representation(2)' can we obtain both a $\sin$ and a $\cos$ component?I think we can only obtain either $\sin$ or $\cos$ component.

Comment: @justin The representations are mathematically equivalent. If two cos/sin functions with *equal* frequency are added the result is another cos function with the same frequency but in general different amplitude and phase.

Comment: @Deve:But what about with an $\cos$ and $\sin$ function.Can we represent this using 'representation(2) in Matt L's answer.

Comment: @justing: Yes. Eq (2) from Matt's answer is equivalent to the definition in your question. I can post a derivation if you're interested.

Comment: @Deve:could you post the derivation.

Comment: @justin: It's already in my answer.